# Possible to check if AVPlayerLayer is visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

Is it possible to check if an `AVPlayerLayer` which is *added as a sublayer* to a ViewController's subview's layer is visible or not? Basically if at any point of time, another view be laid over the said subview, I require to pause the `AVPlayer`, even if it is obscured partially. Note that I set the `zPosition` of the `AVPlayerLayer` to -1 when adding it as a sublayer. The implementation is in a framework that I'm working on so I have no control if the end developer puts another subview over the subview or inside the subview that contains the `AVPlayerLayer`.

Some things to consider are that someone(end developer using my framework) could:

- Add multiple subviews over the the subview or inside the subview with my player
- Add a sublayer to the subview with my player, thus obscuring the player

Any help is appreciated.